# What is the term for the simple, label/sticker like holograms?

Tags: hologram

From my everyday experience I can say that there are 2 types of holograms. One is the simple type that one can find on the important papers, paper money, as excise marks on the alcoholic beverages, as some simple security labels - they are those nice, shiny, metallic 2d pictures which changes color from one angle to the other. I am looking for the technical term for this type of hologram.

There is other type of hologram - scientific one, which is etched on the glass and which is demonstrated in classroom and I have hardly every seen them outside classroom. As I understand then this type of the hologram is the true hologram.

But what is the term for the first type of hologram? I guess it is different from "hologram". E.g. when I enter into ebay or amazon the search term "hologram" then I am getting those serious glass like structures, but I would like to find shiny pictures on the paper, maybe even the hologram book. So, my conclusion is that there is another term which I should use to find artistic paper like holograms, what it is?

Comment: Synthetic hologram? Or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-generated_holography ?

Comment: Yes, "synthetic hologram" is good term, I checked it in ebay and there are some products, but still - in nineties there were those hologram stickers, nice, shiny, glittering, metallic-like pictures. I thought that this form of art would have developed today in very interesting products, but ebay, amazon gives nothing worthy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embossed holograms are those made by stamping plastic (e.g.) with a pattern.  That is the process which is used for credit cards, etc.  The pattern is generated with [a rainbow hologram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_hologram) which is then converted to a stamping plate.

Embossed holograms are true holograms (unlike, e.g. the 'holograms' of dead entertainers, which are just 'Pepper's Ghosts' reflected off a sheet of glass.)

The glass-plate holograms you see in the classroom are can be produced photographically, but the photographic plate can then be converted to a stamping plate for cheap reproduction.

More details are at [the holowiki site](https://holowiki.org/wiki/Embossed_Holograms), but 'embossed hologram' is the googlon which will get you to someplace you can buy them.